# Better way of binding a promise handler to its class

Tags: javascript, promise, this

I have a class that has a single boilerplate function which handles errors on my promises.

```
export class AuthError {
  constructor () {
    this.foo = "Something important!";
  }

  catch (e) {
    if (e.hasAProblem) this.foo.bar();
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I use this function in other classes as a handler, it is of course bound to window.

```
myFunApiCall('baz').catch(authError.catch);
```

I can fix that with a `.bind`

```
myFunApiCall('baz').catch(authError.catch.bind(authError));
```

But I'm really not a fan of that syntax, especially when I know my catch function will never want `this` to refer to anything other than its class.

Is there a way I can give my function a permanent `this` reference its class?

Comment: `.bind()` or `(...args) => authError.catch(...args)`

Comment: @zerkms Can you elaborate? I don't really know where either of those go or how they help.

Comment: `myFunApiCall('baz').catch(authError.catch.bind(authError));` or `myFunApiCall('baz').catch((...args) => authError.catch(...args));`

Comment: @zerkms - it's highly arguable that that's a better syntax. The answer is no, there is no way to give your function a permanent `this` reference. You can just as easily write `.catch(function(e) { authError.catch(e); })`, but to be frank, I have no idea what syntax you dig enough to be okay with.

Comment: @Adam 2 things: 1. I have never stated anywhere it's better, I just provided all possible options as of ES2015 2. It's not an answer but a comment

Comment: What do you actually need this class for? You could use a function that returns an object, without any hassle about `this`.

Comment: @Thomas I need to inject an Angular 2 service into the class (that's stored on the `this` reference). I'd prefer a function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the `catch` method in the constructor, you can forcefully bind a method to its object by declaring it this way:

```
function AuthError() {
    this.foo = "Something important!";
    this.catch = function() {
        // use this here
    }.bind(this);
}

var authError = new AuthError();

myFunApiCall('baz').catch(authError.catch);
```

This makes each `.catch()` method on each object of that type a unique function that is pre-bound to the instance from which it came.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can use this with the class syntax as well, just as long as I create the function in the constructor.

Comment: @Harangue - Yes, the operative part is that you can't define the pre-bound method with the ES6 syntax.  It has to be assigned in the constructor because you are literally creating a new bound function in each constructor call.  I modified the wording of my answer to reflect that.